# Java search a string for a substring UNLESS preceded by specific character

Tags: java, string, loops, substring

I'm attempting to write a Java program that searches for a specific substring (xyz) within a user-entered string, and keeping a running count, unless that substring is preceded by a period. At this point in the class, we've only used charAt and length, so if possible I need to stick to that. Additionally, we haven't used regular expressions at all, so that's out the window too.

I've managed to get the program working as desired, with one notable exception: if the String entered **begins** with a period, it fails to count any successive matches. This is what I've got so far:

```
System.out.println("Give me a String:");
String s1 = kb.nextLine();

int index = 0;
int count = 0;

while(index <= s1.length() - 1 && s1.charAt(index) != '.')
{
        if(s1.charAt(index) == 'x' && s1.charAt(index + 2) == 'z')
        {
            count++;
        }
        index++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Hint: you will need two loops. First loop to iterate over user input, `char-by-char`. Second nested loop to iterate over `xyz` and match with current character of user input.

Comment: I probably already know the answer to this, but is it possible to accomplish this using nested while loops, or would it necessitate using for loops? If both are possible, is it just significantly cleaner to use for loops? Unfortunately, I find it extremely difficult to understand how nested for loops will work without repeated trial and error, but if that's the optimal solution here, then that's what I need try to do. Ty!

Comment: Hint - you have a logic problem. Consider the input: xyzxazxfz or the input: x

Comment: It also seems the requirement is to ignore any "xyz" that is _immediately_ preceded by a "." since you say "if the String entered begins with a period, it fails to count any successive matches" so you also need to consider the input xyz.axyz - this should output 2 but the output of your code above is 1

Comment: Assuming I understand correctly the requirements are to count the number of "xyz" substrings ignoring all ".xyz" substrings. If this is the case then you can do it with a single loop.

Comment: After further testing, it seems you're correct. The s1.charAt(index + 2) == z statement is insufficient to definitively determine that the string is, in fact, "xyz" as opposed to "xaz." Further, any string smaller than 3 characters (such as "x") throws a boundary exception. It doesn't appear that the second part of my conditional statement in the while loop (s1.charAt(index) != '.') is working as I had thought, either.

In any case, you've all nudged me in the direction that I need to take, and I'm confident that further investigation/trial & error will lead me to the answer I need.

Comment: One solution is to iterate across the characters of the input while keeping track of the number of characters matched in the pattern up to the current position. If your counter reaches the last character in the pattern, you've got a full match. If however you find a non-matching character, you reset the counter to zero. You can then modify this following a similar logic to deal with a pattern where the preceding character must not match. (Note: in the form described, this algorithm only works if there are no repeated characters in the pattern.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this seems like a homework type of question I will attempt to guide you in the right direction first and provide a solution at a later time. **I strongly encourage you to work through the problem on your own first to the best of your ability before you look at my solution (once I post it) and to read [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) before going ANY further**

First, consider the kinds of inputs you could receive. Since you didn't specify any limitations you could get things like:

- "" (empty string)
- "\n" (whitespace)
- "x" (a single character)
- "xx" (two characters string)
- "abc" (string of correct length, but not containing your substring)
- ".xyz" (the substring to be ignored)

I could go on, but I'm sure you can come up with all the various combinations of weird things you might receive. These are just a few examples to get you started (along with those I posted in the comments already)

Next, think about what you need your algorithm to do. As I said in the comments it sounds like you want to count the occurrences of the substring "xyz" while ignoring the occurrences of the substring ".xyz". Now consider how you're going to look for these substrings - you're going to advance one character at a time from left to right across the String looking for a substring that matches one of these two possibilities. When you find one of them you'll either ignore it or count it.

Hopefully this helps and as I said, I will post a solution later after you've had some time to wrestle with the code. If you do solve it go ahead and post your solution (maybe edit your question to add the new code or add an answer) **Finally I once again strongly urge you to read** [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) **if you have not already.**

**EDIT #1:**

I wanted to add a little more information and that is: you already have a pretty good idea of what you need to do in order to count your "xyz" substring at this point - despite the small flaw in the logic for inputs like "xaz", which is easily fixable. What you need to focus on is how to ignore the substring ".xyz" so think about how you could implement the ignore logic, what does it mean to ignore it? Once you answer that it should start coming together for you.

**EDIT #2:**

Below you will find my solution to the problem. Once again it's important to understand how the solution works not just copy and paste it. If you simply copy my code without understanding it you're cheating yourself out of the education that you're trying to gain. I don't have time at the moment to describe in detail why and how this code works, but I do plan to edit again later to add those details.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Give me a String:");
        String s1 = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println(countSubstrings(s1));

    }

    public static int countSubstrings(String s1){
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (index < s1.length()-2) {
            if(s1.charAt(index) == '.' && s1.charAt(index+1) != '.'){
                index++;
            }
            else if (index+2 < s1.length() && s1.charAt(index) == 'x' && s1.charAt(index + 1) == 'y'
                    && s1.charAt(index + 2) == 'z') {
                count++;
                index+=2;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

**EDIT #3:**

Here is the nuts and bolts of why the above code does what it does. First, we think about the fact that we're looking for 3 items (a triple) in a specific order within an array and if we see a fourth item (a period) immediately preceding the first item of the triple then we need to ignore the triple.

Per my previous edit we need to define what it means to ignore. In this case what we mean is to simply not count it and move on with our search for valid substrings to count. The simplest way to do that is to advance the `index` without incrementing the `count`.

So, ask yourself the following:

- When should my loop stop? Since we're looking for triples we know we can stop if the length of the input String is less than 3 or when there are less than 3 characters left in the String that we have not examined yet. For example if the input is "xyzab" by the time we get to index 3 we know there's no possible way to form a triple where "a" is the first character in the triple and that therefore our counting is done.
- Is there ever a time when I would not want to skip the next 3 characters after a period? After all the goal is to look for triples so wouldn't I want to skip 3 characters not just 1? Yes there is a time when you do **NOT** want to skip 3 characters and that's when you have something like ".axyz" because a valid triple could start as soon as the 2nd character past the period. So in fact you want to skip only 1 character.

This, and the fact that index is always incremented by 1 at the end of the loop (more on this later), is why the first condition inside the `while` only advances the `index` by 1:

```
if(s1.charAt(index) == '.' && s1.charAt(index+1) != '.'){
    index++;
}
```

- Is there ever a time when I would see a period and not wish to ignore (skip) the next character? Yes, when the next character is another period because it could indicate that another triple needs to be skipped. Consider the input "..xyz" which would result in a wrong answer if you encounter the first period and skip the second period since your algorithm could see the next three characters as a valid triple but in fact it is invalid because of the second period.

This is why the second half of the above condition exists:

```
`&& s1.charAt(index+1) != '.'`
```

- Now ask yourself how to identify a valid triple. I'm sure by now you can see how to do this - check the current character, the next character, and the character after that for the values you want. This logic is the latter portion of the second `if` condition within the while:

  `s1.charAt(index) == 'x' && s1.charAt(index + 1) == 'y'
                  && s1.charAt(index + 2) == 'z'`

Whenever you're using calculations like index +1 or index +2 inside of a loop that is incrementing the index until it reaches a boundary you have to consider the possibility that your calculation will exceed the boundary because you can't rely on the loop to check this for you as the loop will not perform that check until either the end or beginning of the loop (depending on which kind of loop it is)

- Considering the above you must ask yourself: How do I prevent out of boundary scenarios when I use these index+1, index+2, etc types of calculations? The answer is to add another piece to your condition:

`index+2 < s1.length()`

You may be wondering - why not add two checks since we're using index+1 and index+2? We only need one check to see if the greatest index we use will exceed the boundary in this case. If index +2 is beyond the bounds we don't care if index+1 is or is not because it won't matter we can't possibly have a matching substring.

- Next, inside of the second `if` inside the `while` you see there is code to increment the index by 2: `index+=2;` This is done for efficiency since once we have identified a triple we know there is no way to form another triple with characters that are already part of another triple. Therefore we want to skip over them and just like the first bullet point we take advantage of the loop incrementing the index so we only need to increment by 2 and let the loop add the extra 1 later.

Finally we reach the end of the logic within the loop. This part you're already familiar with and that's the `index++;` which simply increments the position within the String that we're currently examining. Note that this works in tandem with the first bullet point. Take the example from the first bullet point of ".axyz". There is a period in index 0 and the character in index 1 is not another period so the logic from the first bullet point will increment index by 1, making it 1. At the end of the loop index is incremented again making it 2 thereby skipping over the period - at the start of the next loop index is 2, it was never 1 at the start of the loop.

Well, I hope this helps to explain how it all works and illustrate how to think about these sorts of problems. The basic principle is to visualize where your current element is and how you can use that to achieve your goal. At the same time think about what kinds of properties the different elements of your program have and how you can take advantage of them - such as the fact that once you identify a triple it is safe to skip over those characters because they have the property of only being usable once. As with any program you always want to try to create as many test inputs as you can to test all the weird boundary cases that might occur to ensure the correctness of your code. I realize you probably are not familiar with [JUnit](http://junit.org) but it is a very useful tool and you might try researching the basics of using it when you have a little spare time, and the bonus is that if you use the [Eclipse IDE](http://eclipse.org) it has integrated JUnit functionality you can use.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, D.B. In the interest of full disclosure, yes this is a hw problem. If I gave the impression that I was attempting to obfuscate that, my apologies. At one point, the code I had was working with the one exception mentioned, but I must have changed something along the way prior to this post. I'll wrestle with this more tomorrow, and will hopefully have solved it. If not, feel free to post the solution, as it is due tomorrow evening. Thanks again.

Comment: @SunDevil329 I added a little more advice to the answer that I thought might be useful while you work on your algorithm today.

Comment: It turns out that I have a bit more time to work on this than I thought, so I've only read as far as your first edit. While I have a good idea as to how to fix the logic and boundary issues, it's the algorithm that deals with ignoring matches with a preceding period that I anticipate will be the most challenging aspect. I'll definitely be tackling this first thing tomorrow, and will then mark this question solved. I am tremendously grateful for the in-depth explanation, as I truly want to understand how this works. As you said, copying and pasting will only hurt me in the long run.

Comment: If it helps, write down several examples and step through them on paper. You could also add logging in key areas of the code that are tripping you up or that might be useful (some calls to `System.out.println(...)` would do for your purposes here). There are many different ways to achieve your goal, so if your code looks a little different it may be perfectly fine from a functional standpoint. Testing thoroughly is what will tell you whether you have a problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can simply check the input string whether it starts with period. If so then  you can use the following piece of code to handle the validation.

if(s1.charAt(0)!='.')
{
while(index <= s1.length() - 1 && s1.charAt(index) != '.')
{
        if(s1.charAt(index) == 'x' && s1.charAt(index + 2) == 'z')
        {
            count++;
        }
        index++;
}
}
else
{
    index=1;
    while(index <= s1.length() - 1 && s1.charAt(index) != '.')
    {
            if(s1.charAt(index) == 'x' && s1.charAt(index + 2) == 'z')
            {
                count++;
            }
            index++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: The edited code contains only charAt and length attributes of String

Comment: Thank you for this! I had a feeling that the problem of the string starting with a period could be solved with an if/else statement, and the answer is surprisingly simple (simply starting the index at 1 in the else section). That said, it's now clear that my original code is not working as I had thought. Will post completed code once I've got this figured out. Thanks much!